# Doctrine Custom Repositories - Redeclared class error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am pretty new to Doctrine2 and am trying to setup custom repositories, but am getting an error I can't seem to google my way out of:

Here is the Entity:

```
// entities/Customer.php
namespace Entities;

/** @Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\CustomerRepository") 
 *  @Table (name="customer") */
class Customer { /* ... */ }
```

And here is the Repository:

```
// repositories/CustomerRepository.php
namespace Repositories;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CustomerRepository extends EntityRepository {
  public function getAllEnterprises() {
    return $this->_em->createQuery(
      'SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE column_x IS NOT NULL')->getResult();
  }
}
```

PHP yells at me and says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Entities\Customer in
>   entities/Customer.php on line 10

PHP 5.4.6, doctrine installed via composer.

bootstrap.php:

```
// bootstrap.php
if (!class_exists('Doctrine\Common\Version', false)) {
  require_once "bootstrap_doctrine.php";
}

require_once "entities/Customer.php";
require_once "repositories/CustomerRepository.php";
require_once "entities/Location.php";
```

bootstrap_doctrine.php

```
// bootstrap_doctrine.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration 
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
            array(__DIR__."/entities"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
  'driver'      => 'pdo_mysql',
  'host'        => 'localhost',
  'user'        => 'someuser',
  'password'    => 'somepassword',
  'dbname'      => 'somename',
  'unix_socket' => '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this work. It appears the problem had nothing to do with what I posted, but with the code I used to test this. Executive summary (which now seems obvious) the `->find()` members of `EntityManager` and whatever `->getRepository()` returns are not at all the same. Combine that with Referencing a Class without it's namespace, and here is what happened:

I had:

```
$customer = $em
  // ->getRepository('Customer')
  ->find('Customer', (int)$cid);
```

and was trying to get uncommenting the second line to work. I'm guessing a little here, but I belive what happened is this somehow caused doctrine to look for a class `Customer` (not `Entity\Customer`), and I told it I keep my entities in the `entities` folder.. and there it finds a `Customer.php`... which it happily tries to load.

And yes that would re-define `Entity/Customer`, which wasn't even the class it was looking for.

Furthermore once I fixed that you get a transaction error, because the repository (which already is the right one for `Entity/Customer`) doesn't need the name of the class as the first argument (in retrospect, of course!).

I do have to say that the error messages I get from Doctrine have so far always been proven to be essentially useless. This worries me about adopting it.

Thanks to everyone who took time looking at this, and whoever properly tagged this as Doctrine2 instead of Doctrine.

The correct way to use this for reference:

```
$em->getRepository('Entity\Customer')->find((int)$cid);
```

or

```
$em->getRepository('Entity\Customer')->getAllEnterprises();
```